# Как расположить блок меток с различной длиной контента внутри

Tags: html, css, frontend, figma

Верстал тут сайт по макету из figma.[image: Макет Figma].
Есть такой вот блок, в принципе все очень легко, но вот возникли проблемы с частью "All Tags". Нужно, что бы этот блок прижимался к контейнеру размером 300 пикселей слева и справа. border radius: 28px., f-sz: 14px. Прикинул несколько вариантов, но сделать по макету не вышло. Даже идей нет, как это сделать ровно как на изображении...

[image: All Tags]

Comment: Обычный флекс - ничего особенного.

Comment: Но как сделать так, что бы была разница во внутреннем отступе. Так-то я сделал, но кнопки получаются с одинаковой шириной(

Comment: Не обессудьте, я только вчера начал ознакамливаться с программированием в целом, начал с фронта, поэтому наверное такие глупые вопросы задаю..

Comment: как я понял, вам предлагается использовать комбинацию [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) + [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis). потыкайте интерактивные примеры, будет понятно, как эти свойства работают. если не получится, напишите свой код только для тегов (раз все остальное понятно как верстать) и попросите поправить его, если он не так как нужно отображается.

Comment: так же можно заметить на макете, что размеры блоков фиксированы и не соответствуют точно тексту. так что можно и без флексов обойтись, а вставить 3 дива (block), в каждом по 2 дива вложенных (inline-block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 14em;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Business</span>
  <span>Experience</span>
  <span>Screen</span>
  <span>Technology</span>
  <span>Marketing</span>
  <span>Life</span>
</div>
```